# How to contact a poster directly without putting a comment on a particular answer?

Tags: support

I wish to contact someone who has answered several of my previous questions. I wish to know if they have generalised their approach. Do I have to just choose one of their answers and add a comment that asks an unrelated question or is there a way of contacting him or her more directly?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, that or via chat.

Comment: Don't have more to add than: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/233085

Comment: @Kuba  Thanks. Good reasons. I can see boths sides of issues.